# On Bitnami's Jenkins Run Docker Commands in Jenkins shell ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitnami

I was trying to run docker during jenkins build rather then using docker plugin i was searching to run docker's command in shell.

bitnami jenkins use `tomcat` user and for ssh login it use `bitnami` default username.

I have purchased jenkins from bitnami on aws ec2. I was facing User permission issue and tried lots of solution & searched for 2 days.

- I did changes in `sudoers` file using `sudo Visudo`
- made new user with `jenkins` name try to change default user in jenkin 
  shell
- Removed `Tomcat` user name form ubuntu

I was knowing it is only permission issue but i was stuck on user permission of shell

Comment: Can you share what specific task you're trying to perform, what the actual error messages is, and what you actually changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just simple Do ssh login to instance
2. open terminal
3. change to jenkin shell default user

   sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: This is a **major security problem**.  Anyone who can run any Docker command can trivially access or edit edit any file on the host and very easily become root, and you've opened up that ability to any local user or process.

Comment: yes i know it is harmful for security reason but to there was no other option to solve the issue.